# SPXERR_GSTREAMER_NOT_FOUND_ERROR when using mp3 file with Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services

I have this piece of code throwing the wrror in the title:

```
using (var audioInput = AudioConfig.FromStreamInput(new PullAudioInputStream(new BinaryAudioStreamReader(new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(audioFile))), AudioStreamFormat.GetCompressedFormat(AudioStreamContainerFormat.MP3))))
using (var recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer(config, sourceLanguageConfig, audioInput))
```

`audioFile` is the path to mp3 file with audio to transcribe.

I have installed the latest GStreamer **gstreamer-1.0-msvc-x86_64-1.17.2.msi** for Windows and added it to the User's PATH and set **GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86**. That did not work.

In the docs here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-codec-compressed-audio-input-streams?tabs=debian&pivots=programming-language-csharp

> Handling compressed audio is implemented using GStreamer. For
> licensing reasons GStreamer binaries are not compiled and linked with
> the Speech SDK. Developers need to install several dependencies and
> plugins, see Installing on Windows. Gstreamer binaries need to be in
> the system path, so that the speech SDK can load gstreamer binaries
> during runtime. If speech SDK is able to find libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll
> during runtime it means the gstreamer binaries are in the system path.

It says it will look for **libgstreamer-1.0-0.dll** which is no longer included in the latest version (1.17.2) so I went back to **gstreamer-1.0-x86-1.14.1** which does have the required dll, but still getting the same error.

From Visual Studio 2019 console I can invoke exe files included in that folder so I know the PATH is set correctly.

Anyone has an idea what's missing?

Answer (score 5):

the way i fixed this... (similar to Artur Kędzior)

use version 1.14.5 of Gstreamer https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/pkg/windows/1.14.5/gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.14.5.msi - complete setup

use version 1.13 of Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech (Nuget package)

Go to environment variables on your pc and add to the User variable called path the following C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin

then add a system variable called "GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86_64" (without the quotes) and the value to "C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64"

you may need to reboot if still having issues. but this is now working for me.

Answer (score 1):

Got help with it here https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/issues/764

Basically:

1. Do not use the latest version of Gstreamer
2. Use this one https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/pkg/windows/1.14.5/gstreamer-1.0-x86_64-1.14.5.msi
3. Set **PATH** to bin folder (C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin)
4. Set **GSTREAMER_ROOT_X86_64** variable (C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64)
5. Reboot the machine
6. Set Visual Studio build configuration to **x64**